# System.IO.IOException: 998 (Invalid memory access location) sporadically appearing when running .NET unit tests

Tags: c#, .net

Really stabbing in the dark with this error.

We recently started randomly seeing this error when running a suite of unit tests for a C#/.NET project (.NET Framework 4.7.2).

```
  Failed ConfMultiProjectUniqueBaseline [26 s]
  Error message:
   The test method OPUS.UnitTest.NonRegressionTests.ConfMultiProjectUniqueBaseline raised an exception : 
System.IO.IOException: (998) Invalid memory access location: [C:\(...)test_plug.exe]
```

Re-executing the CICD pipeline (i.e., the **exact** same code is running) sometimes works.

Sometimes the error pops up for a completely separated test. It is completely sporadic.

I have absolutely no clue :

- What this error means
- Why it only started appearing now (on +1 year old tests)
- Why it sometimes "fixes on its own" by restarting the pipeline.

A few additional info :

- All our unit tests read/write from a randomized, unique location initiated at the beginning of the test. This means NO other process can possibly be writing at the same location at the same time. This also means the targeted file does NOT already exist before being created. The randomized location starts from a fixed root (e.g. `C:\output\<randomized_part>\`)
- The code is compiled by the build machine, using MSBuild version version 17.2.1+52cd2da31
- The tests are ran on the same machine, using `vstest.console.exe` version  17.2.0-preview-20220401-07 (x64)

I have no idea what to do at this point. I cannot debug the code, since the error appears very sporadically. It also, mysteriously, never occurred on my machine. Any hints ?

Comment: Are you able to run in debug mode and set Visual Studio to break on all exceptions?

Comment: I guess I could, but we have 200+ unit tests, most of them handle expected exceptions internally. Wouldn't I have to press F5 for each of those internal exceptions ? Plus, this error appears sporadically and does not appear most of the time.

Comment: Visual Studio let's you run tests individually.

Comment: Yes, but this error pops up randomly, on any test that writes to files. Not a particular one.

Comment: It isn't that complicated. Pick one of the tests that fails, run it in debug mode with Visual Studio set to break on exceptions. Then when it breaks, try and figure out what is happening.

Comment: Is the build machine on-premises? Have you tried swapping out the memory?

Comment: @JonathanWood thing is, I already set a loop to run the test around 2K times on my local machine, the exception never popped up. It might be more frequent on the build machine, but if it is, I won't have access to a debugger at that point (the machine does not have Visual Studio installed, and is not easily accessible)

Comment: @IanKemp the build machine is on premise indeed. I would have hoped to find some hints that indicate this error is definitely caused by memory corruption or something, but I guess I can give this a try beforehand.

Comment: @ArthurAttout [MemTest86+](https://memtest.org) is a good way to check.